# Java Servlet Printing "language/content type/page encoding" line in browser

Tags: java, html, css, servlets

I am working with a java servlet and have encountered a dilemma with my code. When I test the code inside eclipse on the built in web browser, the code works perfectly. But when I go to the browser to test, every thing is perfect except for:

```
<%@ page language=\"java\" contentType=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\" pageEncoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"%> ( ---> printed via out.println("<%@...");)
```

printing in as the first content on the page (top left).  If I comment this line out, I lose all of my css styling even though my link and meta tags in my header state the following:

```
link rel='stylesheet' href='landingpage.css' type='text/css' media='screen'

meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'
```

(both also via out.println())

which cover my stylesheet reference, content type, and properly mapped charset. And just for clarity's sake, `"out"` is my printwriter `(out = response.getWriter())`

Can anyone provide an answer for how I can get this line to go away from my browser?

Thank you.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            System.out.println("driver found");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;" +
                    "instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Timecard_DB;user=Dan;password=Mc177700;");

            out.println("<%@ page language=\"java\" contentType=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\" pageEncoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"%>");
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<link rel='stylesheet' href='landingpage.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>");
            out.println("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'>");
            out.println("<title>Home</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");

            out.println("<div id='container'>");

            out.println("<div id='header'>");
            out.println("<img src='Images/mPowerlogo.jpg'/>");
            out.println("</div>");

            out.println("<div id='welcome'>");
            out.println("Welcome, User1");
            out.println("</div>");

            out.println("<div id='logout'>");
            out.println("<a href=''>Logout</a>");
            out.println("</div>");

            out.println("<div id='links'>");
            out.println("<ul>");
            out.println("<li><a href=''>Timecard Management</a></li>");
            out.println("<li><a href=''>User Management</a></li>");
            out.println("<li><a href=''>Customer Management</a></li>");
            out.println("<li><a href=''>Admin</a></li>");
            out.println("<li><a href=''>Reports</a></li>");
            out.println("</ul>");
            out.println("</div>");

            out.println("<div id='feed'>");
            out.println("<p>Recent Activity:</p>");
            out.println("<textarea id='feedtext' readonly>"); 

            try {
                stmt = connection.createStatement();
                String feedSelect = "SELECT ROLE_NAME from ROLES";
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(feedSelect);
                ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
                while(rs.next()) {
                    for(int i = 1; i <= metadata.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                        String colValue = rs.getString(i);
                        out.println(colValue);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

            out.println("</textarea>");
            out.println("</div>");

            out.println("</div>");

            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>"); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
        }

        response.setContentType("text/html");
    }
```

CSS:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

body { 

.... so on so forth; the styling is fine.
```

Everything else in my code functions exactly as it should. It is simply the first line printed via my printwriter that is printing inexplicably on the page.

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: I just added the code and the charset from my css file

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if any problem occurs

Answer (score 3):

As its a servlet so you need not to write this line `out.println("<%@ page language=\"java\" contentType=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\" pageEncoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"%>");`
Generally we write this line in jsp and when its compiled in the server like tomcat then this line is ommited

You need to add this line in servlet

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: I tried this with the omission of that first line, and also with that first line still present. Neither changed either result. Where should this line be placed? The constructor automagically calls doGet() so I should just be able to place the setContentType() in doGet() like I was doing. Any other ideas?

Comment: @DanMcNamara generally we do in the service method.Well you can also do in the doGet();

Comment: I am only using tomcat6.. could this have anything to do with the issue? Just throwing out the possibility.

Comment: @DanMcNamara no problem if you are using tomcat6.Just tell me if you your problem is solved or not